# Will adding sodium carbonate to a low pH solution of sodium hydrosulfide have an adverse reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am managing an HSE project to dispose of an expired NaHS solution. There was approximately 500 gallons of liquid in two tanks. Both tanks have been pumped down, and there is little residual liquid with ~ 100lbs of solid in the bottom of the tanks. The H2S readings in the tank are approaching IDLH conditions. I am assuming that over time, the pH of the NaHS solution decreased due to exposure to air which is causing the high concentration of H2S in the tank.

We want to suppress the H2S vapors so that when the solids are placed in drums for disposal, there won't be any off gassing in the headspace of the drum. Would adding solid sodium carbonate to the solid in the bottom have any adverse reaction? I am assuming that some heat will be generated due to it neutralizing the H2S, but this is taking place outdoors and we would add the carbonate slowly to minimize heat generation.

Comment: There won't be much heat, but there won't be much neutralization either. H2S is a weaker acid than H2CO3.

Comment: @IvanNeretin if it is actually $\ce{Na2CO3}$, it could work because carbonate ion is a stronger base than hydrosulfude ion. Once you have bicarbonate ($\ce{NaHCO3}$), however, you're dead.

Comment: @OscarLanzi True. But then again, what is it that we are trying to avoid? Is it the possibility of pressure buildup? Then carbonates are no better than sulfides.

Comment: Pressure buildup yes, toxicity they're different. The OP needs to clarify his objective.

Comment: For disposal of *solids*, from  https://www.cpc-us.com/images/2017SDS/sulfursds/SDS_Sodium_Hydrosulfide_Flake_February_14_2019.pdf : "Use a Ferric Chloride solution to precipitate sulfur and ferrous sulfide, then filter and send the cake to a landfill for industrial waste." BTW, if the pH is *too* low (e.g., excess NaOH added), then waste is classified as *corrosive*, as well as *toxic*.

Comment: @OscarLanzi we are trying to increase the pH of the solid/sludge mixture to decrease the rate of hydrogen sulfide evolving from the contents of the tank, so that when it is placed in closed containers in can be handled safely. Why would bicarbonate forming be a problem? It’s a weak base with a pH of 9 in solution

Comment: Bicarbonate forming would be no problem, it's just ineffective. You therefore need the normal carbonate salt and then you get only 1:1 molar neylutralization, not 2:1.